# LayoutInflater not working as expected

Tags: android, xml

I was told to create a custom layout to alter the default size of my dialog box. I can't seem to get it working.

Here is where the dialog is built:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null));
ad.setMessage("message");
ad.show();
```

And here is the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View android:id="@+id/dialog_view"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What is it doing? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I want my dialog box to be a fixed size (400x400 dp). It is just doing the standard behavior, which is to wrap around its contents (which is just a string).

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't you call `builder.setView(...)` before you call `builder.create()`?
EDIT: You could also do this with one long chain: `new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null)).setMessage("message").show()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the alert dialog from builder after setting its view:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null));
AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
ad.setMessage("message");
ad.show();
```

Comment: `LayoutInflater.from(context)` NOT `context.getLayoutInflater()`